# How can we ignore the enter button press as a character in c programming at the time of taking input from user?

Tags: c, input, while-loop

Look at the example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;
    while(scanf("%c", &ch))
    {
        if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' ||
                ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'A' ||
                ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' ||
                ch == 'U')
        {
            printf("It's Vowel\n");
        }
        else if((ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'))
        {
            printf("It's Consonant\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong Input/ It's not Alphabet\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling this example code,  when I enter 'a', The output is "It's Vowel" and "Wrong Input/ It's not Alphabet". I think the cause for this output is, the compiler takes the character also takes the enter press as a character.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Add a test  `if (ch == '\n') break;` or maybe `while(scanf("%c", &ch))` --> `while(scanf(" %c", &ch))`.  What do you want to happen after a `'\n'` is detected?

Answer (score 1):

> I think the cause for this output is, the compiler takes the character also takes the enter press as a character.

It's not the compiler who takes characters. Getting input is a run-time operation. When the program is already running, the work of the compiler is far done, but beside that your guess is correct. It is because `scanf()` doesn't consume the newline character with made by the press to <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the first step.

This newline character then get read at the next iteration by `scanf("%c", &ch))` and as the newline character is a legit character it is stored inside of `ch`.

> Is there any way to solve this problem?

Use

```
while(scanf(" %c", &ch))
```

instead of

```
while(scanf("%c", &ch))
```

Notice the white space character (`' '`) before `%c`. This will fetch the abandoned newline character left in `stdin` from the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you so very much!! I find the solution from your answer.

Comment: Thank you so very much!! I find the solution from your answer.

Comment: @AlamgirHossain If you think this answer was the most helpful one or solved your problem, feel free to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thank you.